# Magic Record Threaded Saves

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, magicalrecord, mknetworkkit

I can't quite figure out the correct way to do this. I am having trouble persisting the object I create in the block.

```
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {

            User *u = [User MR_createEntity];
            u.name = @"bob";
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_save];

    } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

Cant quite seem to get bob persist when I reopen the app. Can someone explain what is happening? I think that u is created in a new context? and then this is not merged with the main context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force `u` to be created in the same context as the context you're trying to save, and then save with `u`'s context.

```
User *u = [User MR_createInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];
u.name = @"bob";
[[u managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Comment: `MR_save` is now deprecated. Please use `MR_saveToPersistentStore*` instead.